# Can I simply plug in a second video card to connect a third and fourth monitor?

Tags: graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors, desktop

I have a desktop PC with a dedicated videocard that has 2 Displayport sockets.
I want to connect a third (and maybe fourth) monitor later on.

Is it possible for me to simply purchase any videocard that fits in the available PCI slots and use that to connect the additional monitor(s) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on which operating system you use. All modern versions of Windows will support this easily.

I recommend you "stay within a family" (i.e. if you have AMD, buy AMD again or if you have nVidia chose nVidia again), as I have seen artifacts when mixing vendors.

Comment: The PC is running Windows 10 so I'm assuming we're in the clear! Thanks for your fast response!